# Trouble with keeping process launched by systemd service alive

Tags: systemd, services, systemd-timer

I am trying to to get my first `systemd` service working as desired. Here is what I have:

`gateway-watchdog.service`:

```
# A systemd service for the Gateway Watchdog

[Unit]
Description=gateway-watchdog: Watchdog to ensure that Gateway (gateway.py) is running

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/lora_gateway/
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/lora_gateway/watchdog.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`gateway-watchdog.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gateway-watchdog: Timer to run the associated gateway-watchdog service

[Timer]
# Run service 1 minute after boot
OnBootSec=1min
# Run service 15 minutes after the last run
OnUnitActiveSec=30s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

`watchdog.sh` has these lines (contained in some `if` statements):

```
#!/bin/bash
...
if [[condition]]; then
    command="python3 gateway.py"
        # Process needs to be run in the background with '&'. If it isn't, the systemd service will treat this script
        # as still running and so not re-run it at the time specified by the timer service.
    echo "2 $(date +'%F %T'): Running: $command" >> $LOG_FILE_PATH
    eval "$command"
        # Command must be run using eval. If it isn't, the ampersand at the end of the command is effectively ignored
    exit
fi
```

What I need:

The service will run `watchdog.sh`. If the `if` conditions in the script are true, `watchdog.sh` will launch `python3 gateway.py` as a separate process and then exit, and the service will no longer be considered active so that it will run again 30 seconds later.

Through various combinations of different service `Type`s (I've tried `simple`, `oneshot`, and `forking`), using `&` at the end of `ExecStart` and/or my command line, and/or using `nohup`, I am able to either launch and keep `gateway.py` alive, or have the service run every 30 seconds, but not both.

When `python3 gateway.py` stays alive, it always stays part of the service's `CGroup`, so the service stays `active (running)`.

How can I change this behavior to achieve what I'm trying to do? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:
I have updated the file contents above to reflect changes made based on suggestions from U.

With the files as given above, `sudo systemctl status gateway-watchdog.service` gives:

```
● gateway-watchdog.service - gateway-watchdog: Watchdog to ensure that Gateway (gateway.py) is running
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gateway-watchdog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-01-13 01:45:25 UTC; 8s ago
TriggeredBy: ● gateway-watchdog.timer
   Main PID: 30684 (watchdog.sh)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 4435)
     CGroup: /system.slice/gateway-watchdog.service
             ├─30684 /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/lora_gateway/watchdog.sh
             └─30696 python3 gateway.py

Jan 13 01:45:25 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started gateway-watchdog: Watchdog to ensure that Gateway (gateway.py) is running.
```

Good: The `gateway.py` process stays running.
Bad: The service does not run again 30 seconds later, because the previous run is still active.

If I put the `&` back into `command="python3 gateway.py &"`, `sudo systemctl status gateway-watchdog.service` gives:

```
● gateway-watchdog.service - gateway-watchdog: Watchdog to ensure that Gateway (gateway.py) is running
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gateway-watchdog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2022-01-13 01:49:05 UTC; 6s ago
TriggeredBy: ● gateway-watchdog.timer
    Process: 33724 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/lora_gateway/watchdog.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 33724 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 13 01:49:05 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started gateway-watchdog: Watchdog to ensure that Gateway (gateway.py) is running.
Jan 13 01:49:05 ubuntu systemd[1]: gateway-watchdog.service: Succeeded.
```

Good: The service is inactive, so it does run again 30 seconds later.
Bad: The `python3 gateway.py` process dies immediately.

Comment: Please avoid "bash script.sh"; instead make the script executable using "shebang". Likewise avoid "command &" commands; let systemd handle it. Assist the community to help you by providing the journal output your commands produce.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `watchdog.sh` does contain `#!/bin/bash`. I have changed `ExecStart=bash watchdog.sh` to `ExecStart=sudo /home/ubuntu/lora_gateway/watchdog.sh`. Despite having `WorkingDirectory` set, it seems that I have to give the full path here.

Comment: I have updated the post with `systemctl status` output.

Answer (score 0):

I have arrived at a solution by referencing https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041270/2909854.
The `command` line in `watchdog.sh` is now:

```
command="systemd-run --scope -E setsid nohup python3 $GATEWAY_SCRIPT_PATH"
```

I also had to change my service `Type` set to `forking`, and add a `TimeoutSec=1`. Not sure if the timeout is necessary, but it helps at least when debugging.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. As we do not have the programs you are using, it's hard to reproduce the problem. Maybe it would have been useful to set up a primitive service that basically does the same (just some daemon process shell script (watchdog) and the timer setup). If you just wanted to run the service after boot, there are easier ways: Just add the required systemd dependencies; no timer needed.